# What is the best practice to duplicate a site collection?

Tags: powershell, site-collection, site-template, backup, restore

I have a site collection, that contains sub-sites and other list that have different level permissions.

If I use the "Save as template" I don't obtain a satisfied result, because template loses the permissions settings etc.

I thought to create a site collection to use as template and then to use a backup/restore procedure to clone this site collection.

Is this a right way?
And How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I found an answer, just for site collection created on web application root.

Use this command to backup a site collection

```
Backup-SPSite -Identity "http(s)://your-site-collection-url" -Path "C:\backups\your-site-collection-backup.bak"
```

It's important to use an absolute path as -Path parameter.

Then create a new web application and then run the following command

```
Restore-SPSite "http(s)://your-new-web-application-url" -Path "C:\backups\your-site-collection-backup.bak"
```

I hope that this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

couple of things you can do.

1) Backup curent site collection and then restore it with different name & url.

2) you can use export Site Collection and Import site collection. You will lose the metadata etc.

3) you can use the 3rd party tool for this, which give you more power & flexbility and less effort. try ShareGate migration tool. they have 15 days trial, try it.

Comment: My favorite is the 1, thank you. I described below how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online - the way to do this is via PnP :-

```
Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Url -Out   to get the provisioning Template

Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path to Apply the template to the new site / Site Collection
```

This will get all of the site columns, site content types, term store, list definitions,  (empty) lists, Site Structure and copy them to the new site.

If you want content moved across as well, then that needs more PowerShell, but is doable.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do that is to use Copy-SPSite cmdlet. I had to create several site collections based on one original site collection that was created as a "template". Created the template site collection in its own db (use CA or New-SPSite to add a db to a web application). Then every time I need a new site collection:

1. Create a new site collection db.
2. Use Copy-SPSite to copy the template site collection to a new one on the new db.

Copy-SPSite: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161280.aspx

My dba was a little annoyed by the number of databases created but we learned that to put each site collection in its own db eases SharePoint admin tasks (backup/restore/move/quotas/etc.).

Comment: Be aware that there is a limit of 500 content databases per farm: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ContentDB