# SharePoint 2019 Server, Site Templates

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

I am trying to copy a Site Collection that has a Design Package from one SharePoint Server to another.  I've tried using ShareGate and I've copied over all the Master Pages and Page Layouts in the Master Page Gallery.  I've tried Creating a Design Package and then importing the Design Package in the new site.  The Home Page does not render correctly and it seems like the Page Template for the Welcome Page is corrupted because it displays like a broken image.

Answer (score 0):

See: [How to copy site collection to another server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52780/how-to-copy-site-collection-to-another-server)

And: [What is the best practice to duplicate a site collection?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93359/what-is-the-best-practice-to-duplicate-a-site-collection)

For copying a site collection in PowerShell:
Use the `Backup-SPSite` command to create a backup of your site collection.

```
Backup-SPSite -Identity <URL of the site collection> -Path <Path to save the backup file>
```

Use the `Restore-SPSite` command to restore the backup on the new server.

```
Restore-SPSite -Identity <URL of the new site collection> -Path <Path of the backup file>
```

For the corrupted page, reset to site definition:
[Cannot access SharePoint Online site because of corrupt master page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110240/cannot-access-sharepoint-online-site-because-of-corrupt-master-page)

Let me know if this helps.